# Source IP is modified on UDP packets

Tags: networking, udp, arp

I have a linux server S, with two netcards, one ('netA') on 192.168.1.x and the other  (netB) on 192.168.2.x. netB is connected by point-to-point wifi to the rest of netB.

To get netB card to find netA, I had to enable proxyARP on the netB card. All was well till I tried a pair of programs which use UDP to communicate with each other (one on netA, the other on netB).

[image]

The server seems to change the source IP of the netA side app request into netB's IP. (monitored remotely with tcpdump):

```
# On netA's card:
11:42:36.107179 IP 192.168.1.102.4321 > 192.168.2.101.4321: UDP, length 17

# One netB's side:
11:43:02.172829 IP 192.168.2.115.4321 > 192.168.2.101.4321: UDP, length 17
```

The result being that the client program on netB doesn't recognize the sender.

No NAT is enabled on the server.

Can anyone think of a cause of this IP translation? And can I, on netB's side, identify the real packet source?

Comment: Maybe its not net A that is doing the changing but instead the proxy on net B? Can you check and see if the proxy is changing the source, and putting the real one under some other header?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'm quite sure it's the server which changes the IP. Both outputs in the original question have the same size, so the original IP is not somewhere in the packet. (both packets are monitored on the server with TCPDUMP -i eth[0|1]

Comment: Are your PTP Wi-Fi devices in "WDS" mode?

Comment: No... the Wifi is set to bridge point-to-point. But the source IP changes *before* it is sent back on through the wifi. In the example above, the ptp link is at the '>': 192.168.2.115 > 192.168.2.101.